# Laravel Count Vehicles W/O Images

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get some help to rewrite some stuff that got thrown at me on a project I am working on to increase speed. I am working in **Laravel 5.4**. I can trying to count how many vehicles do not have images without looping through each vehicle.

Each vehicle has a vehicle_id that corrects to the vehicle_id col in the vimages table.

I am trying to eliminate having to loop through every single vehicle and make separate SQL calls for each vehicle.

My Function To Count:

```
    'missingDescription' => $inv->where('vehicle_type','=','NEW')->where('description','=', '')->where('description','=', null)->count(),
```

Original Function To Count:

```
 'images' => $inventories->filter(function($row) {
            if ($row->Images()->get()->count() <= 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })->count(),

        'stockphotos' => $inventories->filter(function($row) {
            return $row->Images()->get()->filter(function($item) {
                return $item->isStockPhoto && !$item->isDeleted;
            })->count() > 0 ? true : false;
        })->count(),
```

Images function:

```
public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vimage');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use withCount. so when you get the model originally add withCount('images') which will append images_count to the returned model.

```
$inventories = Inventory::withCount('images')->get();

'images' => $inventories->where(images_count, 0)->count()
```

Here's the laravel page for reference [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a search closure for the description, since you're looking for where it's either an empty string OR null.

```
'missingDescription' => $inv->where('vehicle_type','=','NEW')
                              ->where(function($query) {
                                  $query->where('description','=', '')
                                     ->orWhereNull('description');
                               })->count(),
```

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, I am looking for assistance with images. Thank you anyways.